how to make the function called when closing tab. Flask
I have a form and I want the user to be warned when closing the tab that the data will be lost. I figured out the modal window. Now I need to call it when closing a tab. I am not familiar with JS. Is there a way to implement this on Flask?
I searched the Internet and found nothing

Flask is a server side technology, it doesn't know anything about the events happening on the client side. You will have to use JavaScript.

This is normally done using the beforeunload event in JavaScript.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
